# How to Gain Access to WebSocket Connections Within an Isolated Function

Tags: websocket, concurrency, ballerina

I'm working on developing a Ballerina WebSocket service with the goal of receiving messages and broadcasting them to all connected WebSocket clients.
To achieve this, I'm looking to make some modifications to the service's 'onMessage' function. Specifically, I need to pass the 'connections' map, which holds the connectionID for each WebSocket client.
However, I'm facing an issue where I can't access these connections due to the function being isolated.

I'm wondering if there's a solution that would allow me to gain access to the connections, or if there's an alternative approach to meet my requirements? This the code I have tried

This is my code

```
map<websocket:Caller> connections = {};

service class ASB {
    *websocket:Service;
    
    remote function onOpen(websocket:Caller caller) returns error? {
        connections[caller.getConnectionId()] = caller;
    }

    isolated remote function onMessage(string message) returns error? {
        check broadcast(message, connections);
    }
}

isolated function broadcast(string text, map<websocket:Caller> connections) returns error? {
    foreach websocket:Caller caller in connections {
        if caller is websocket:Caller {
            check caller->writeTextMessage(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to make the module level `connections` map as isolated. Then the connections variable can be accessed directly within the broadcast message with `lock` as below.

```
import ballerina/websocket;

isolated map<websocket:Caller> connections = {};

service class ASB {
    *websocket:Service;
    isolated remote function onOpen(websocket:Caller caller) returns error? {
        lock {
            connections[caller.getConnectionId()] = caller;
        }
    }

    isolated remote function onMessage(string message) returns error? {
        check broadcast(message);
    }
}

isolated function broadcast(string text) returns error? {
    lock {
        foreach websocket:Caller caller in connections {
            if caller is websocket:Caller {
                check caller->writeTextMessage(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more details see [isolated-variables](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/isolated-variables/)